# How to randomly select an item from an array and display in form field

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, web

I've been trying to randomly select an item from an array and displaying the chosen array in a form field. I've found how to display the item in a paragraph by using `<p id="item"> </p>` (might be incorrect) but can't figure out how to display it in a form field :/ Help, please.

Comment: What do you mean by "display in form field"? What code have you tried, what did you except to get, what did you actually get?

Comment: Could you maybe post your current code in a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1527820/838733

Comment: I'll use jsfiddle to show you my attempt to doing this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Tc4Pm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a random value like this

```
var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
```

Then you can display it in the form field by using

```
document.getElementById('id1').value = rand
```

where `id1` is the id of your formfield